# Configure Bluetooth PAN between keyboard-less/GUI-less Ubuntu server and Kubuntu laptop

Tags: ubuntu, networking, bluetooth, kubuntu, headless

I want to configure a Bluetooth PAN between an Ubuntu server and my laptop (Kubuntu). Does anyone have any pointers on how to accomplish this?

I've plugged in a USB Bluetooth dongle and I'm not sure where to go from here. The output of `lsusb` shows the device:

```
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
```

---

The reason:

I have set up an HTPC based on Ubuntu Server. It only has WiFi connectivity because getting CAT5 to it is not worth the effort.

I want to mess around with various WiFi settings, but still have an alternate method of SSH'ing to the box when I inevitably break the WiFi, hence I figured Bluetooth PAN should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already read [this](http://bluez.sourceforge.net/contrib/HOWTO-PAN)? Here's a paste from the relevant section (I think):

> Here's an example:
>
> To connect a PANU node
>   (00:37:5C:67:D3:01) with a GN
>   (00:37:5C:67:D3:02), BlueZ must be
>   operational on both sides. The GN must
>   be able to run as Bluetooth master
>   (see above).
>
> Enter     # modprobe bnep
>
> on both nodes. Then enter     # pand
>   --listen --role GN
>
> on the GN side.
>
> After that, you you can connect from
>   the PANU side:    # pand --connect
>   00:37:5C:67:D3:02
>
> In case of problems, the system log
>   files under /var/log/ (i.e. 'messages'
>   and 'warn') may give you further
>   information about the cause of
>   failure.
>
> Note that it is a good idea to start
>   'pand' as server on the GN (or NAP,
>   respectively) rather than the PANU,
>   since then you have a consistent
>   access scheme from any possible PANU.
>   When you do so, 'pand' permanently
>   listens for connection attempts from
>   other nodes, thus becomes resident. In
>   case you have only one PANU, however,
>   you may also swap roles and start
>   'pand' as server (i.e. using the
>   '--listen' parameter) on the PANU
>   side, and connect from the GN (or NAP)
>   side.

**EDIT**: Just found [Blueman](http://blueman-project.org/), a graphical bluetooth manager for dialup networking, bluetooth audio, pairing and so on.